# I can’t access PDFDocument properties after initialising PDFView

Tags: swift

I’m working on a react native app with a bridge from Swift to handle PDF files. I am trying to simply get the total number of pages of a given PDF document.

I have tried to initialise the PDFView class and set a document url. But when I try pdfView.document!.pageCount, I cannot access the int because pdfView.document is nil

```
pdfView = PDFView()
pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url)
pageCount = pdfView.document!.pageCount // crashes here every time
```

I would expect pageCount to hold the value of the total number of pages in the document. Instead the app crashes due to unexpected unwrapping of nil optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unexpected wrapping of nil optional means that the PDF document doesn't exist. You need to either check the URL or the location of the PDF document.

I suggest you don't use force unwrap ('!') unless necessary. Use '??' instead and give a default value.

Comment: Thank you - this worked. The problem was that I was using a package to store the file in React Native (RNFS) and then immediately asking Swift to read the document. Using a promise in React Native to only read the document in Swift once the document was uploaded was the solution here.